# Flutter - I'm trying to print a textbox according to api response

Tags: api, flutter, dart, conditional-statements

I have an API that returns some data, In my API there is a data group called `addonCat`,

I need to check this `addonCat` key's value with `if` and shows the textbox if it is not null..

I coded something like this

```
Text(dish.addonCat == null ? " " : "Available",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red, 
    fontSize: 14
  ),
)
```

`addonCat` declared as `final List addonCat;` in pojo class.

This is how I'm receiving the value from the response `addonCat: json['addonCat']`

Now the textbox is shows for every data from the api.

What I'm doing wrong, Any suggestions would be helpfull.

Comment: The problem is `your list == []` not `null` so you need to do something like this, `dish.addonCat.toString != '[]' ? " " : "Available",`

Comment: there is a warning `equality operator == invocation with references of unrelated types`.. after restart there is no change

Comment: past the full code please

Comment: I only changed the condition. Which code do you need

Comment: wait, my bad `dish.addonCat.toString() != '[]' ? " " : "Available"`, `toString()` is a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to check it on the right direction
so instead of `null`, check if it's an empty list just like this..

```
Text(dish.addonCat.toString() != '[]' ? " " : "Available",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red, 
    fontSize: 14
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you wouldn't put in an empty Text widget as it's more expensive than just having an SizedBox, which is the simplest Widget you can have while still occupying the spot in your tree. You would implement it like this:

```
dish.addonCat == null || dish.addonCat.isEmpty
  ? SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0),
  : Text("Available",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red, 
      fontSize: 14
    ),
  ),
```